# Dar baixa no estoque com Triggers SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

comecei a fazer um curso sobre SQL e estou em duvida em relação aos triggers
esta é a tabela

```
create table Produto (
    codProduto int primary key identity(1,1),
    Nome varchar(50),
    Quantidade int,
    Preco smallmoney
);
create table ItemVenda (
    codVenda int identity(1,1),
    foreign key (codProduto) references Produto(codProduto),
    codProduto int primary key,
    Quantidade int
);
```

preciso fazer um trigger para que após eu dar insert na tabela venda produto seja debitada a quantidade inserida na tabela produto, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Qual SGBD? É mysql ou sql-server?

Comment: é o sql-server.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/477cc21d-083a-4df2-8bbf-4d3446d3710a/trigger-para-atualizar-o-estoque?forum=transactsqlpt exemplo tão comum que se acha fácil no Google e afins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na maioria dos casos o ideal é não guardar atributos de cálculo nas tabelas, porém se você quiser fazer uma `TRIGGER` para isso, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tgr_itemvenda_ai', 'TR') IS NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER tgr_itemvenda_ai ON ItemVenda FOR INSERT AS BEGIN SELECT 1 END');
END;
GO

ALTER TRIGGER tgr_itemvenda_ai
ON ItemContrato
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE p
     SET p.Quantidade = p.Quantidade - i.Quantidade
    FROM Produto p
         INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.codProduto = p.codProduto;
END;
GO
```

---

A sugestão que te dou para não ter necessidade de usar `TRIGGER` é utilizar uma tabela estoque em que você realize o fechamento mensalmente ou conforme a sua necessidade:

```
CREATE TABLE Estoque(
  codEstoque INT  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  codProduto INT  NOT NULL,
  Quantidade INT  NOT NULL,
  Inicio     DATE NOT NULL,
  Fim        DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_EstoqueProduto FOREIGN KEY(codProduto) REFERENCES Produto
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Considerando que você tenha uma coluna `data` na tabela `Venda`:

```
SELECT e.codProduto,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e.Inicio, 103) AS Inicio,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e.Fim, 103) AS Fim,
       e.Quantidade - SUM(iv.Quantidade) AS disponivelFim
  FROM Estoque e
       INNER JOIN ItemVenda iv ON iv.codProduto = e.codProduto
       INNER JOIN Venda v ON v.codVenda = iv.codVenda
 WHERE v.data BETWEEN e.Inicio AND e.Fim
 GROUP BY e.codEstoque,
          e.codProduto,
          e.Inicio,
          e.Fim,
          e.Quantidade
```